# Use of "whether" without "or not"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> The pattern depth in courses is dependent upon the number of feeds with selection facilities and **whether** the selection can be changed during knitting.

This sentence has been recited from **Knitting Technology** by **David J Spencer**. If the above sentence was written in the following way, it could make sense to me.

> ........**whether** the selection can be changed during knitting **or not**.

I don't know when only **whether** is used, and when **whether** is used with **or not**. When only **whether** is used, please say, what does it mean?

Comment: As far as I know, when *whether* works roughly as a two-choice *if*, we can drop *or nor*. However, we don't normally drop the *or* part when it means "it doesn't matter (whether ... or ...)”.

Comment: Adding or leaving out "or not" doesn't change the meaning.  We usually leave it off if the meaning is clear without it.  For example: "Are we going to make apple pie today?"  *"That depends on whether we can get apples at the store."*  Leaving off "or not" is perfectly normal, because it's the obvious alternative: we can either get apples or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Whether** and **whether or not** mean exactly the same thing. The books on writing style I've seen often recommend leaving off the **or not** because it only makes the writing wordier.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, if you could add an example, the OP is asking for usage.